# Allow Keyboard for double touch on UITextField in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Hi i have UITableview cell with textfield  i want allow keyboard for second touch only if text field is appear for first click it has to be disappear and second tap it has to be appear can any one help me. here i have attached my sample code

==================================================================================

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
[self.playerTable.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx,BOOL*stop)
     {
         UITableViewCell *cell = obj;

         if([cell isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
         {
             for(UITextField *textField in cell.contentView.subviews)
             {
                 if([textField isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
                 {
                    if ([textField isFirstResponder])
                     {
                         [textField resignFirstResponder];
                     }

                 }

             }

         }
     } ];

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: and - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}

Comment: Thanks in advance can any one help me

Comment: you mean double tap (like quickly pressing two taps on textField)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have got solution for my question

```
#pragma mark TextField methods

    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
[self.playerTable.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx,BOOL*stop)
     {         UITableViewCell *cell = obj;
                  if([cell isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
         {             for(UITextField *textField in cell.contentView.subviews)
             {                 if([textField isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
                 {                     if ([textField isFirstResponder])
                     {                         [textField resignFirstResponder];
                                          }
                                      }
                              }
                      }
              } ];
    return YES;
}
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{  int tapcount;    tapCount = tapCount + 1;
if (tapCount%2==0){        [textField becomeFirstResponder];
        [cursorView removeFromSuperview];
                   tapCount = 0;        }else{
        {        [cursorView removeFromSuperview];
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{ [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
```